# Git pre-commit hook to check for a string and exit code 1 if the string exists

Tags: bash, git, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to get a pre-commit hook to work, to check the stagged files and read the difference to check for a few strings. If the strings exist, commit has to fail.

```
#!/bin/bash
#import os

echo "Running pre-commit hook" 
checks=os.environ["APPSETTING_DEVPASSWORD"],os.environ["APPSETTING_DEVUSER"],os.environ["APPSETTING_DEVPASS_ELMAH"]



git diff --cached --name-status | while read x file; do

      if [ "$x" == 'D' ]; then continue; fi
    for word in $checks
    do
        if egrep $word $file ; then
            echo "ERROR: Disallowed expression \"${word}\" in file: ${file}"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
done || exit $?
```

It still commits the files even though the strings exist in the files. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to bash.

Answer (score 5):

It must be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running pre-commit hook" 
checks=($APPSETTING_DEVPASSWORD $APPSETTING_DEVUSER $APPSETTING_DEVPASS_ELMAH) # create an array

git diff --cached --name-status | while read flag file; do
    if [ "$flag" == 'D' ]; then continue; fi

    for word in ${checks[@]}
    do
        if egrep -q "$word" "$file"; then
            echo "ERROR: Disallowed expression \"${word}\" in file: ${file}" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: can I add the same hook on the server side to enforce to all the developer machines?

Comment: You cannot force a `pre-commit` hook to the developer hosts, but you can set up a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) to stop push. `pre-receive` or `update` hooks, I think. Please be careful — every hook has a different set of arguments and stdin data and server-side hooks usually don't have access to files (bare repositories) so you will need to use `git grep` or extract files from commit objects and trees to disk.